# Copy image from one ImageView to another

Tags: android, imageview

I have an `ImageView` (A) with its image re-sized (zoomed in) using `Matrix` transformation. How do I assign another image to another `ImageView` (B) keeping size and position from the ImageView A?

Comment: getMatrix() and getDrawable() methods can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
B.setDrawable(A.getDrawable());
B.setImageMatrix(A.getImageMatrix());
```

Comment: Tried that - did not work for me. Have you tested it? Can you please post the entire class implementation?